# send grant_type and client_id using C language

Tags: c, curl

Am new to cURL and am trying to implement OAuth 2.0 using C language cURL calls. The cURL option that am using to send the grant_type is:

```
result = curl_easy_setopt(active_curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "grant_type=authorization_code");
```

However with this the responce tha am getting from server is

> "{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"Method not allowed""

Am not sure if this is the right way to send data.

Comment: The "method" in "method not allowed" may refer to the HTTP request type you are sending.  Are you sending GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Even though was not able to get the exact thing that I was looking for i.e. in C however I was able to get a cURL command run directly to send the data to server. And hence would like to resolve this query of mine.